# How to initialize a callable object?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, callable-object

I am learning default template argument today and everything is ok at first, but now I encounter some problems.

```
template <typename T, typename F = std::less<T>>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2, F f = F()) {
    if (f(v1, v2)) return -1;
    if (f(v2, v1)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I know `F` is the type of a callable object and `f` is a callable object, but what does the `F()` mean? A type and an operator()?  
And what makes me more confused is that `F()` doesn't accept anything whereas `f(v1, v2)` accepts 2 objects. The initialization confused me a lot.  
If anyone can help me figure out these codes, I would be very grateful.Thx.

Comment: `F()` is a temporary of type `F`, constructed with a default constructor. `f(v1, v2)` calls `F::operator()` (which presumably takes two arguments) on an object of type `F`.

Comment: You can even combine the two and write `F()(v1, v2)` - this creates the temporary, then immediately calls `operator()` on it. Roughly equivalent to `F temp; temp.operator()(v1, v2);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Now I understand it totally, thank you!